# Wordpress Media URLs?

Tags: posts, images, uploads, media

I just launched a Wordpress site after having done all of the standard procedures: moved the uploads folder, uploaded the database, and did a search and replace on all of the urls in the database. Everything is fine, except for all the media that is uploaded specifically in the content area of the posts. All of these URLs, when you click on the image, say the correct URL, but for some reason on the front end, and inside the post area the images are going to localhost instead.

For example, the image URL clearly says http://curioquilt.com/path/to/image,

But inside the post and on the front end they aren't being displayed and the server is looking for http://localhost.com/path/to/image.

There are no instances of localhost anywhere in the database. If you do go to the site (http://curioquilt.com), you have to go into the archive and click on a deeper post to see this, as I have gone through and manually fixed the first 15-20, but would rather not have to do this for the other hundred.

Thanks.

Comment: For the db search and replace did you use [search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)?

Comment: @bonger Yes, same one I always use.

Comment: Just looked at the site and perhaps you've changed things but it appears the images are stored at "http://curioquilt.sisyphus.io/cnt/uploads" rather than "http://curioqulit.com/cnt/uploads" so subbing the former for the later should fix things shouldn't it?!

Comment: That's weird. I did seem to miss 42 instances when I did the first Search & Replace. But the problem still exists with the images. It's shouldn't be a database issue particularly because WP is looking for the images inserted in the posts in http://localhost instead of http://curioquilt even though the URLs are stored as the latter.

Comment: I'm not seeing "localhost", only broken images like [here](http://curioquilt.com/b-o-c-breakfast-of-champions/). When I manually sub "curioquilt.sisyphus.io" for "curioquilt.com" in the image url I get the [image](http://curioquilt.sisyphus.io/cnt/uploads/2013/07/1F4A9704.jpg)

Comment: This is what I am getting on that page:

GET http://localhost/cnt/uploads/2013/07/1F4A9704.jpg 404 (Not Found) 

Does yours say curioquilt.sisyphus.io instead of localhost?

Comment: It says curioqulit.com instead of localhost, http://curioqulit.com/cnt/uploads/2013/07/1F4A9704.jpg not found

Comment: This is maddening. The uploads folder contains that image in that exact location.

Comment: Permissions perhaps?

Comment: Nope, checked that too.

Comment: Ha, "curioqulit" != "curioquilt" - you've reversed the "l" and the "i"!!

Comment: Goshhhhh. What a stupid mistake. Veery nice. Everything is fixed now. I almost feel better it was that rather than something programatic. Thanks a ton.